# How does the ORDER BY CASE Clause Work in the following Code?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

How does this part of code work?

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN subject IN ('Chemistry','Physics') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
  subject, 
  winner;
```

Comment: Since it's ASC by default the 0's would come first. Those subjects which are not chemistry or physics would be first in the results, alphabetically  by subject, then by name.  Then, Chemistry then physics with each winner of each subject listed alphabetically; but only for 1984.  Put simply, Chemistry, then physicals will be the last two subjects, Whereas every other topic would be listed alphabetically ahead of those 2.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. I kindly ask you to read the two pages: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and especially: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
While your question might be valid, it would be nice, if you include the question itself in the body, not just in the title.

Comment: @xQbert Helped me. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it checks if subjet is Chemistry or Physics.
If it does the sorting score will be 1.

If the subject does not contain any of "Chemistry" or "Physics" the score will be 0.

After that it sorts the results by score so the results that contains Chemistry or Physics will come first after that those that dont contain.

Comment: Almost got it. You say that results which contain Chemistry or Physics come first and those that dont come next. But the code gives Chemistry and Physics at last

Answer (score 0):

It orders by the result of the case, then by subject, then winner.

Rows that are not chemistry or physics come out first, in order by subject and winner. Then chemistry, then physics.

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want `SELECT winner, subject FROM nobel WHERE yr = '1984'  AND subject IN ('Chemistry','Physics') ORDER BY CASE;`